# EPPlus: Creating Sort Columns

Tags: c#, .net, excel, epplus

I am trying to create an excel spreadsheet like so in EPPlus:

[image: Desired Output]

My main trouble stem from getting the drop down to appear. I understand this can be easily done in desktop Excel by selecting the Data -> Filter tool.

Is there any way to achieve this result using EPPlus? (Or any other built in .NET method)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I achived this result using the following line of code:

```
ws.Cells[$"A{row}:S{row}"].AutoFilter = true;
```

Comment: order by a column ?